# capturing column from a delimited file using args

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have the following file:

```
123 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 567
321 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 765
```

I wrote this script for capturing `first | last` columns:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$(cat input.txt | sed 's/ //g')
args=(${line//|/ })
x="${args[0]}"
y="${args[11]}"
echo $x
echo $y
```

The result is:

```
123
765
```

how can I get the following result:

```
123 | 567
321 | 765
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F '[| ]+' '{print $1, $NF}' OFS=' | ' file
123 | 567
321 | 765
```

**Doing this in pure BASH:**

```
while IFS=' | ' read -a arr
    echo "${arr[0]} | ${arr[@]:(-1)}"
done < file
123 | 567
321 | 765
```

Comment: Thanks but I have done it with:`awk -F'|' '{print $1 "|" $6  $11}' input.txt` and `awk  '{print $1, $10, $11}' input.txt
` I want to use the structure of bash written in post and `sed` or `awk`

Comment: But as you can see with this simple `awk` you don't need anything else.

Comment: If you want to do that in BASH it will require a loop.

Comment: OK Thank you very much...how to change the columns? for example column 3 and 2? I want to get the pattern,,pardon :)

Comment: You can easily get column 3 or 2 using `${arr[2]}` OR `${arr[1]}`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `sed`

```
sed 's/|.*|/|/' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you..but how I can change the script in this part:`sed 's/ //g'` This is a exercise

Comment: `sed 's/|.*|/|/;s/ //g' input.txt`

Comment: `sed "s/ |.*| /|/' input.txt` including directly the space into the first pattern in this case (no other space)

Answer (score 3):

I could get it with `cut`

```
$ cut -f1,6 -d"|" input.txt
123 | 567
321 | 765
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do in bash:

```
$ cat file 
123 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 567
321 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 765
```

```
$ while IFS="|" read -ra line; do 
    echo "${line[0]}|${line[${#line[@]}-1]}"
done < file
123 | 567
321 | 765
```